# i want to show UIAcitivityitems in grid view on UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivitycategory

In my app i'm sharing some URL contents to Whatsapp, Google+ like this it will showing in `UIActivityViewController`.

In this `UIActivityViewController`

Facebook, Twitter, Whatsapp, Google+, etc.. these all are showing in a row like this below screen shot.

[image]

Is it possible instead of showing in row i want to show in gridview like this

[image]

Comment: I think you need to write your own custom UIActivityView and play with the user interface that you want to apply.

Comment: @ErAcube if u have any idea on that can u refer some stuff regarding custom `UIActivityView`

Comment: Check once: http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/2012/10/objective-c-custom-uiactivityviewcontroller-icons-text/

Comment: @iOS_Ramesh  I'll check and let u know thanq